# Bokeh Bar plot |

Tags: python, bar-chart, bokeh

I am trying to Create a bokeh bar chart using Python. The data2 is the values

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show,hplot
from bokeh.charts import Bar

data2=[65.75, 48.400000000000006, 58.183333333333337, 14.516666666666666]


bar = Bar(values=data2,xlabel="beef,pork,fowl,fish",ylabel="Avg consumtion", width=400)

show(bar)
```

Error

```
TypeError: Bar() takes at least 1 argument (1 given)
```

What am I doing wrong Here?

Answer (score 3):

The `bokeh.charts` API (including `Bar`) was deprecated and removed from Bokeh in 2017. It is unmaintained and unsupported and should not be used for any reason at this point. A simple bar chart can be accomplished using the well-supported `bokeh.plotting` API:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

categories = ["beef", "pork", "fowl", "fish"]
data = [65.75, 48.4, 58.183, 14.517]

p = figure(x_range=categories)
p.vbar(x=categories, top=data, width=0.9)

show(p)
```

[image]

For more information on the vastly improved support for bar and categorical plots in `bokeh.plotting`, see the extensive user guide section [Handling Categorical Data](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html)

Answer (score 0):

***Note from Bokeh project maintainers:*** This answer refers to an obsolete and deprecated API. For information about creating bar charts with modern and fully supported Bokeh APIs, see the other response.

---

You might want to put all of your data in a data frame.

To directly plot what you want without doing that, you need to remove the "values" keyword.

```
bar = Bar(data2,xlabel="beef,pork,fowl,fish",ylabel="Avg consumtion", width=400)
```

This won't add your x-labels though. To do that you can do the following:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show,hplot
from bokeh.charts import Bar
from pandas import DataFrame as df
data2=[65.75, 48.400000000000006, 58.183333333333337, 14.516666666666666]

myDF = df(
  dict(
    data=data2,
    label=["beef", "pork", "fowl", "fish"],
    ))

bar = Bar(myDF, values="data",label="label",ylabel="Avg consumption", width=400)

show(bar)
```