# What is name error and how to solve this error

Tags: python, bokeh

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.io import output_notebook
output_notebook()
df = pd.read_csv("covid_19_india.csv")
melted_df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Date'], value_vars=['ConfirmedIndianNational', 'Deaths'])
melted_df.head()
p = Bar(melted_df, label="Date", values="value", group="variable", legend="top_left",ylabel='Values')
```

I tried this code  and getting a error 
NameError: name 'Bar' is not defined

How to solve this

Comment: NameError broadly means: "Python doesn't know what Bar is".

I'm guessing that Bar is something in the Bokeh library, but I'm not sure that it's the current API

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38731491/add-custom-legend-to-bokeh-bar

suggests that it's outdated: 

> *Note from Bokeh project maintainers: This answer refers to an obsolete and deprecated API. For information about creating bar charts with modern and fully supported Bokeh APIs, see the other response.

Answer (score 1):

You are not importing Bar from the library "bokeh". Just adding this line at the top would solve your problem:

```
from bokeh.charts import Bar
```

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bokeh.charts'
 Getting this error

Comment: Okay, the 'Bar' function under bokeh.charts you're using seems to be deprecated. Instead use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36959406/bokeh-bar-plot)

Answer (score 0):

A `NameError` in Python means that the Python interpreter encountered some variable or function name that it knows nothing about. There are various ways to inform Python of named things:

```py
import pandas as pd # importing them, now "pd" is defined

def foo(): ... # defining a function, now "foo" is defined

bar = 10 # assigning variables, now "bar" is defined

class Baz(object): ... # creating classes, now "Baz" is defined
```

In your code you are trying to use a function named `Bar` but nothing named `Bar` has been imported, defined, or assigned to. Python does not know what the name `Bar` means, hence `NameError`.

in many cases the solution is to add a missing import, but in this case that advice is out of date. There *used to be* a `bokeh.charts` module that had `Bar` function you could import, but `bokeh.charts` was deprecated and removed several years ago at this point. If you are looking to create bar chart or other categorical plots, then Bokeh has much better (and simpler) APIs available to use these days. See the docs section [Handling Categorical Data](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html) for many examples you can refer to.